# If exists then update else insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a `STORED PROCEDURE` that will be used to `UPDATE` a table called `machine`. This table has three columns (`machine_id`, `machine_name` and `reg_id`).

In aforementioned table,`reg_id` (`INT`) is a column whose values can be changed for a `machine_id`.

I would like to define a `QUERY`/`PROCEDURE` to check if a `reg_id` already exists in that table. If it does, then `UPDATE` that row, otherwise `INSERT` a new row.

Can someone please help me to write that `QUERY`/`PROCEDURE`?

Answer (score 17):

Only problem is, you can't use it like a normal query. Control structures like **IF** or **WHILE** are only allowed in stored procedures or functions.

Just create a procedure like this:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure select_or_insert()
begin
  IF EXISTS (select * from users where username = 'something') THEN
    update users set id= 'some' where username = 'something';
  ELSE 
    insert into users (username) values ('something');
  END IF;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

and call it like this:

```
call select_or_insert();
```

and Done

Comment: Hello @Taz, can you check off the answer you went with?

Comment: @Craig Efrein hi. i went with the first one. Answer of yours. Thanks again.

Comment: @Taz I am glad that this information is helpful, please if this answer could remove your doubts proceed to close the question.

Comment: MYSQL doesn't have an command of `IF EXISTS` that can be used. There is an `EXISTS` that you can put into a WHERE clause but I can't see an `EXISTS` that would work like this in the mysql documentation

Answer (score 13):

Hope This helps, [DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
create table machine(
  machine_id int not null primary key,
  machine_name varchar(50),
  reg_id int
);

insert into machine (machine_id, machine_name, reg_id)
values(1, 'my_machine', 1);

INSERT INTO machine (reg_id, machine_id, machine_name) VALUES (1, 1, 'test_machine')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE machine_name=VALUES(machine_name);
```

Work on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac9e5/1/0)

Comment: They may need `reg_id = VALUES(reg_id)` as well.

Comment: what if we have two conditions on query, I mean not only key is unique?